# Azure FHIR search for resources with _include

Tags: sql, azure, hl7-fhir

I have a DiagnosticReport resouce that has an encounter and 3 observation resources references. I am trying to do a search query that would return a Bundle with the DiagnosticReport and all referenced resources so as to not have to do 4 other queries.

```
"encounter": {
    "reference": "Encounter/8720d7d7-68cc-3575-8c79-9de39561324c"
},
"effectivePeriod": {
    "start": "2020-07-01T08:16:00.000Z",
    "end": "2020-07-01T08:16:00.000Z"
},
"issued": "2020-07-01T08:17:03+00:00",
"result": [
    {
        "reference": "Observation/89510c61-8a94-3c65-8832-3397d2a70bfd"
    },
    {
        "reference": "Observation/3d837dbf-3d4c-3742-9b6e-2638d26d8c54"
    },
    {
        "reference": "Observation/618ec246-2d98-3179-a0a2-a0094046f466"
    }
]
```

```
I have tried 
[Base]/DiagnosticReport/{id}?_include=DiagnosticReport:Encounter
[Base]/DiagnosticReport/{id}?_include=DiagnosticReport:Encounter/{id}
Is there a way to get the DiagnosticReport & Encoutner & Observation in one Bundle?

This is an SQL OSS FHIR Server, so according to Documentation _include is supported in the SQL Version of azure.
```

Comment: Please detail with FHIR Server you are using.  Please as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the search parameters when you specify the includes, so in your case:

```
https://fhir-server-url/DiagnosticReport?_id=1234&_include=DiagnosticReport:encounter&_include=DiagnosticReport:result
```

Will return the Encounter and the Observation resources in the bundle.

Comment: I have tried the same and I am getting the below error for the same url. I have inserted data for both Diagnostic report and encounter.
 "code": "forbidden",
 "diagnostics": "The _include search is missing the type to search."

Comment: And I just figured out that we are using cosmos DB for data persistence with azure FHIR service and include only works for sql, is there any way we can query with cosmos ?

Comment: _include only works with the SQL persistence provider. It relies on joins that cannot be performed in Cosmos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FHIR API Service also. I ran across this issue for Encounter and this worked for me.

```
https://lcavantage.azurehealthcareapis.com/Encounter?_id=f1c06cc6-be9c-e673-408e-e6e303d9924a&_include=Encounter:subject
```

I believe this works now because COSMOS DB has had a few updates this question was presented and handles relationships better!